# ibmmq typescript client on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, ibm-mq

I am using ibmmq typescript client on aws lambda.
But when I try to execute my lambda, I get this error :
`

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=93 uv=1 libc=glibc node=16.16.0\n    loaded from: /var\n",
  "trace": [
    "Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=93 uv=1 libc=glibc node=16.16.0",
    "    loaded from: /var",
    "",
    "    at Function.load.path (/var/task/index.js:11218:13)",
    "    at load (/var/task/index.js:11182:34)",
    "    at ../../../../node_modules/ref-napi/lib/ref.js (/var/task/index.js:11363:57)",
    "    at __require (/var/task/index.js:12:50)",
    "    at ../../../../node_modules/ibmmq/lib/mqi.js (/var/task/index.js:63554:15)",
    "    at __require (/var/task/index.js:12:50)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:65749:28)",
    "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)",
    "    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)"
  ]
}
```

`

Is there anyone who has already encountered this error

Thanks :)

I tried to change the nodejs version (from 12 to 18)
I deleted the package.json and restarted npm install

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask]. Think of how you can improve your title, such as incorporating the `errorMessage` into it. Please also see how to make an [mre]. Your question might be answerable as is, but it might not: you might need to tell us more about how you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think you are hitting this https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-napi/issues/49 which indicates that the lambda environment is missing a requisite for `node-ff-napi`. It looks like it needs a c compiler.  An alternative would be to provide your app as a lambda compatible container.